# BigQuery - No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Im getting a weird error(Maybe im getting this error for the first time) from BQ.

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. 
Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [27:1]
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
FROM tbl1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN t3 on t2.id = t3.id
JOIN t4 on t4.id = t1.id
```

Error line `JOIN t2.id = t3.id`  **t2.id** is showing this error.

its an integer column.

Comment: Are you able to add some preview data from `t2` and `t3`? Or can you try casting `t3.id` to int64 with `cast(t3.id as int64)` to rule out type issues.

Comment: You're trying to to join on two columns which are not the same type. Like Eric said, please show us your table schemas, or at least the types of the join columns.

Comment: Hey @GrahamPolley, sure I'll check the data types. The actual BQ query is join 7+ tables. I'll try to check the data types of join conditions, after that I'll push the SQL code somewhere and share the link here.

Comment: @GrahamPolley - can you please write it as the answer, this may help others.

Answer (score 34):

One of your comparisons is mixing types.  This is a bad idea -- as the error message shows.  You need to find out which pair (or pairs) and do one of the following:

```
cast(t2.id as string) = t3.id
t2.id = safe.cast(t3.id as int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is due to syntax error.
So to solve this just copy the generated query and paste it in bigquery then you will know what is wrong.

Answer (score -4):

In your query you created join with `t2` table but `t3` and `t4` table names are not given in join. Below is the correct query.

```
SELECT col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
FROM tbl1 as t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t1.id
```

Try this. I think this will work.

**After Edit**

you need to give table name with field in select fields like

```
select 
    t1.field1, 
    t2.field1, 
    t3.field3, 
    t4.field 
From tbl1 as t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t1.id
```

Comment: hey Lucky Saini, I have wrongly added in my question, my query is exactly the same as which you mentioned above. 
I have updated the question.

Comment: Tried the table alias name. but its not working same error.