# SQL INNER JOIN syntax Error BigQuery // New to SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax, inner-join, data-analysis

I'm getting this error **"No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [9:6]
"** while trying to JOIN two table in BQ, Login ID column is listed in the two tables but BQ shows that there's an error on line 9[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peltJ.png)

```
SELECT
  performance.name,
  performance.ahtdn,
  tnps.tnps,
FROM
  `data-exploration-2023.jan_scorecard_2023.performance-jan-2023` AS performance
  LEFT JOIN 
    `data-exploration-2023.jan_scorecard_2023.tnps-jan-2023` AS tnps
  ON performance.login_id = tnps.login_id
```

I've checked the syntax for INNER JOIN online and on BQ documentation but I couldn't find the reason why I get this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigQuery - No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950386/bigquery-no-matching-signature-for-operator-for-argument-types-int64-strin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be due to trying to join INT64 and STRING column. It should be resolved casting the numeric column to text one like this:

```
CAST(performance.login_id AS STRING) = tnps.login_id
```

or cast the second one if it is the numeric.